# How to set Setters from main and get the Getters from Another Class Java 7

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have 3 classes; 1) Main 2) SettersAndGetters 3) AnotherClass. 
In my main class, I set the setters. And I am looking for a way to access these values from AnotherClass. Right now I am getting a null which is due to the new instance I created. So how can I get round that, how to retrieve the value that I set in main.

```
public class Main{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      GettersAndSetters sg = new GettersAndSetters();
      AnotherClass copyOfSG = new AnotherClass();

      sg.setName("Mo");
      sg.setAge(20);
      sg.setIdNum("77777");

      System.out.print("Name : " + sg.getName() + " Age : " + sg.getAge()+"\n");
      System.out.println(copyOfSG.printout());
      //In here I am trying to print the value that is 
      //in my 3rd class "AnotherClass" but i am getting null. 

   }
}
```

Output:

```
Name : Mo Age : 20
Age: 0
Name: null
```

SettersAndGetters:

```
public class GettersAndSetters{
   private String name;
   private String idNum;
   private int age;
   public int getAge(){
      return age;
   }
   public String getName(){
      return name;
   }

   public String getIdNum(){
      return idNum;
   }

   public void setAge( int newAge){

      age = newAge;
   }

   public void setName(String newName){
      name = newName;
   }

   public void setIdNum( String newId){
      idNum = newId;
   }
}
```

AnotherClass:

```
public class AnotherClass {

    public void printout() {
        GettersAndSetters gs1 = new GettersAndSetters();

        System.out.println("Age: " + gs1.getAge());
        System.out.println("Name: " + gs1.getName());

        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(copyOfSG.printout());`? error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs because you created two independent instances of `GettersAndSetters` in `Main` and in `AnotherClass`. Look:

```
   public static void main(String args[]){

      GettersAndSetters sg = new GettersAndSetters(); //first instance
      AnotherClass copyOfSG = new AnotherClass();

      ...
   }
```

---

```
public class AnotherClass {

    public void printout() {
        GettersAndSetters gs1 = new GettersAndSetters(); //second instance
        ...
    }
}
```

And you're setting properties in *first* instance, but attempting to read it from *second*.
To solve just pass first instance from `Main` to method in `AnotherClass` as suggested by Satya.

```
public class AnotherClass {

    public void printout(GettersAndSetters sg) {
        System.out.println("Age: " + sg.getAge());
        System.out.println("Name: " + sg.getName());        
        ...
    }
}
```

and call it next way:

```
public class Main{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      GettersAndSetters sg = new GettersAndSetters();
      AnotherClass copyOfSG = new AnotherClass();

      ...

      copyOfSG.printout(sg);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. but now I am getting  "void type not allowed here" for this statement System.out.println(copyOfSG.printout(sg));

Comment: @Moe, sorry, that's my fault. You have invoke just `printout` method, without `System.out.println`. I changed code in my answer. Sorry for 
inaccuracy.

Answer (score 2):

> In my main class, I set the setters. And I am looking for a way to access these values from AnotherClass

Replace

```
System.out.println(copyOfSG.printout());
```

with

```
copyOfSG.printout(sg);
```

and your `printout()` method

```
public void printout(GettersAndSetters gs1) {
       //No need of creating GettersAndSetters object

       System.out.println("Age: " + gs1.getAge());
       System.out.println("Name: " + gs1.getName());

}
```

Comment: Can you modify your answer with a little more detail referencing my code. I made the modification but i am getting errors left and right.

Comment: @Moe in addition to the solution carefully understand what Satya has done. The very fact that you were stuck with this indicates you do not have a grasp of how Java objects work.

Comment: now I am getting  "void type not allowed here" for this statement System.out.println(copyOfSG.printout(sg));

Comment: Thank you so much Satya, for your help on this! it seems that I still need to digest the new way of doing things. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

there is one class `BeanUtil` in `apache library`.It will help you for this. this cass set and get attribute value.

```
BeanUtil.setProperty(<obje_name>, <field_name>, <field-value>);


BeanUtil.getProperty(<object_name>, <field_name>);
```